# How to add a web page with html editor in Iron Speed

Tags: ironspeed

I have a website that I have built by Iron Speed.
I have to add a new web page with HTML editor.

I looked for that about 2 hours and I didn't find any helpful article. All the articles that I have read supposed that there is a table (in the db) that will be covered by the web page. :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry for my English ...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could list the version of Iron Speed you are using?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a page with the HTML editor hooked up to a database field, then Iron Speed Designer will do it for you automatically if the text field in the database is large enough, i.e., if Iron Speed detects this is a large string field it will automatically add the HTML editor for that field.

If you don't have a page created already, just use the application wizard to create an add record or edit record page.  If you have an existing page that already contains your database field, you can also enable the HTML editor for that field via the property sheet. (I'm assuming you're using the current release? Iron Speed Designer v7.X.)

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are good. 

If you want to add different HTML editor than you can create a different Web Page in Visual Studio 

Or other way is just put the whole code of .aspx page in to Cell Editor ...

It will not show in Designer but executes perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Chris you can adjust the settings for when Iron Speed generates a HTML editor under Tools -> Application Generation Options. Then Expand General Application Options followed by Rich Text Editor Controls. Then switch the Threshold higher or lower as you need. I think the default is 500 chars.

This process should work in versions 6, 7 and 8. It might be a little different in earlier versions.